# splash screen wont render on production but render on development (white screen)

Tags: react-native, expo, splash-screen

I have a problem with my app that wont render the image that i set on the splash screen.
only in production it happen in development its working as well.at the development is render the image but on the production its only show white screen.
before 3 months the app was render the image on production but now it show only white screen
I didnt change something any of the configuration on the app

```
import * as SplashScreen from "expo-splash-screen";
import { useState, useEffect, useMemo } from "react";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import store from "./store/Index";
import { LogBox } from "react-native";
import axios from "axios";
import DataProvider from "./context/Data";
import AppContainer from "./AppContainer";
import "./language/Data";
LogBox.ignoreLogs([" Invalid prop `textStyle` of type `array` supplied to `Cell`, expected `object`"]);
SplashScreen.preventAutoHideAsync();
export default function App() {
  const [appIsReady, setAppIsReady] = useState(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    async function prepare() {
      try {
        if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
          axios.get(`${process.env.EXPO_PUBLIC_HEROKU_URL}/latest-lottery`);
        }

        await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 1500));
      } catch (e) {
        console.warn(e);
      } finally {setAppIsReady(true);
      }
    }

    prepare();
  }, []);

  const onLayoutRootView = useMemo(async () => {
    if (appIsReady) {
      await SplashScreen.hideAsync();
    }
  }, [appIsReady]);

  if (!appIsReady) {
    return null;
  }
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <DataProvider>
        <AppContainer />
      </DataProvider>
    </Provider>
  );
}

//App json

{
  "expo": {
    "name": "lottery",
    "runtimeVersion": {
      "policy": "sdkVersion"
    },
    "plugins": [
      [
        "expo-build-properties",
        {
          "android": {
            "enableProguardInReleaseBuilds": true
          }
        }
      ],
      [
        "expo-image-picker",
        {
          "photosPermission": "The app accesses your photos to let you share them with your friends."
        }
      ]
    ],
    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0,
      "url": "https://u.expo.dev/292e68aa-3480-4c01-b697-6672a8d899fc"
    },
    "slug": "lottery",
    "version": "1.0.19",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
    "userInterfaceStyle": "light",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/lotto-background.png"
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": ["**/*"],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true
    },
    "android": {
      "package": "com.liors.lottery.first.project",
      "versionCode": 20,

      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/lotto-background.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#FFFFFF"
      }
    },
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./assets/favicon.png"
    },
    "extra": {"eas": {
        "projectId": "292e68aa-3480-4c01-b697-6672a8d899fc"
      }
    }
  }
}
```